# Zend Db (standard or table gateway) vs Doctrine in Zend 2 - Pros/Cons

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Zend DB (standard way or table gateway) vs Doctrine in Zend 2.
Some might say it’s apple vs orange comparison but I would say since they are substitutes (we use one between two) so it can be compared (as requirements are not always crystal clear).

When I started Zend 2 since documentation, books, tutorials were based on Zend DB or Table Gateway, I used it but I was not happy with ways when we have to work on 2, 3 or more tables joins (multiple table gateway adapters) so I switched to Doctrine ORM (also reading so many saying “doctrine is good for large project”). I was already using doctrine in symfony projects so was not difficult but I also didn’t like doctrine in instance like complex joins between entities (extra works), especially slowness and extra memory compared to Zend DB.

Now I am really confused what should I do? So what do you guys suggest?

From my analysis:

## Table Gateway

#### Pros

- Lightweight (keep things simple)
- Native to Zend (better support now and for future updates)
- More documentation-books
- Better community or user support (as it is what many are working on)
- Close of database-tables (I am good in SQL. So feel good)
- More flexible
- Easier to use other doctrine native features such as ACL

#### Cons:

- Table joins (more complex)
- Primitive in some context
- Handling multiple table gateway instance is difficult.

## Doctrine

#### Pros

- More classes-loosely coupled—better control
- Brings all advantages of using ORM
- Lots of work already on doctrine itself (tutorials-documentations) which works most of the time
- Less reliance on database
- Caching (but also possible with Zend DB Table Gateway)

#### Cons:

- More memory and slower (compared to Zend DB Table Gateway) for medium project
- Adds complexity (extra files+ configurations + its own conventions)
- Sometimes overkill for medium projects
- More work in many to many relationships between entities or complicated joins
- Extra work YAML-Schema
- Less tutorials-books-user support on Zend + Doctrine

Any others? ( for both)

So, in light of these, which one do you suggest? Working on generic CMS that I can extend.

or why Zend DB cannot/should not be used in larger projects?

I found some discussion here but not as per its pros/cons analysis.

Comment: already asked http://stackoverflow.com/q/9061640/949273 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2898604/949273

Answer (score 2):

I did the reverse. I removed Doctrine 2 and switch to Zend DB 2, that improves our queries by a factor of 5x, then we're able to customise some parts of Zend DB table gateway, and we gain 5x more performance on queries (almost as native).

I would say do not use Doctrine if you're gone have large datasets. And remember doctrine consumes a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have switch to doctrine after many years, i think it is very better than `Zend_Db` if you can make it compatible with `Zend`.
Doctrine can `migrate` your database, it means you can update customers databases to latest version just with one command.
Another benefit is your `entities` can implement in several `DBMS` like `mysql`, `mssql`, `mangodb` and ...

For more compatibility you can use [Raman Framework](https://github.com/Ramansoft/Raman/) (this framework add some features to Zend 1.12)

Answer (score 0):

If the following is important to you then I'd say absolutely go with Zend/Db/*

1. Performance
2. Scalability
3. Low learning curve